Knowing that a Mobius strip is described by parametric equations how can I introduce a thickness element to show a constructable model?
I have tried various graphics packages to model a single twist Mobius strip, however none allowed me to identify a way of making the strip anything other than 2D. As an Electrical engineer my math is hitting it's limits here. Please help! Thanks

Your question seems to not quite fit for this site, it is too broad/not specific enough, lacks details and context. It will probably get closed soon. Please see the help center article and how to ask a good question.

Given a parametric representation for your strip, say
$(x,y,z) = R(s,t) = [X(s,t), Y(s,t), Z(s,t)]$, you can introduce a
"thickness" as follows. The cross product $W(s,t) = \dfrac{\partial R}{\partial s} \times \dfrac{\partial R}{\partial t}$ is a vector orthogonal to the surface. A normalized version is $N(s,t) = W(s,t)/\|W(s,t)\|$ where $\|W\|$ is the length of the vector $W$.
So a "thickened" version is
$(x,y,z) = R(s,t) + u N(s,t)$.

Thank you Robert
